# Document should never be Deleted if it is Referred to another Document in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I am new in MongoDB and stuck in one problem. Basically, when one document(i.e A) is referred to another document (i.e B). The document A should never get deleted. But if I first delete the B then only I should able to delete A because now A is not referred to any other document.

I have tried with pre middleware in here is my code

```
    model.collection('inventory').pre('deleteOne', function(next) {
       model.collection('inventory').Inventory.deleteOne({_id: this.id}, { _id: { $ne: this.id } }, {multi: 
        true});
    });
```

below is the schema

````
```
schema 1:
{
_id: 1,
parent_id: null;
name: A
}

schema 2:
{
_id: 2,
parent_id: 1;
name: B
}
```
````

I think it can be achieved by pre middleware approach. Please help me with the code to achieve my outcome. I am also open to the other approach.

Thank You

Comment: Does the referred document and referring document belongs to same collection?

Comment: Thank For your reply Vikash. Yes. It belongs to the same collection.

Comment: can a child document have further more child documents? Also Is `this.id` your parent id ?

Comment: Yes, there can be futher child documents. this.id is not parent id it is a document id i.e _id

Comment: use find query to check if document is parent or not. ex: `model.collection('inventory').find({parent_id: this.id})` if this return empty array then delete the doc otherwise don't delete.

Comment: Is it a good approach to this in pre middleware... Also, I need to use multi: true because I need to find it on multiple documents.

Comment: Then you dont need pre middleware. just find before delete or you can use findAndDelete query